# Стыковка border

Tags: css

поймал ступор на таком моменте, у меня есть несколько блоков в одну линию, каждый имеет `border` в `1 px`, но вот беда, как быть с местом где эти блоки стыкуются, `border` визуально принимает `2px`.
Хочу чтобы визуально все линии были в `1px`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для вертикальных границ элементарно - обнулить border-left или border-right у всех кроме первого/последнего. А вот для горизонтальных как-то даже не знаю

Comment: margin -1px с нужных сторон, только ещё флекс помучать, чтобы сошлось с желаемым результатом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не нужна поддержка `IE`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 1px;
}

.item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Если первый ряд гарантированно будет заполнен

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{
  padding:25px 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}

.item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, про outline стыдно, но не знал

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно решить. Padding контейнера тогда нужно будет убрать, либо внутри контейнера еще один div, сделать к которому применять уже данный подход.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}

.item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Все равно большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант сделать ту же картинку без бордера. В смысле вообще-)) А выглядеть будет как должно.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```